# How to find the owner of a property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, properties

Ok, because my initial question sounds unclear, so I decided to edit it. My question is how do you find out who defined a certain property, for example, the `parseInt` function, how do I know on which object it was definded like if `parseInt` was definded on the `window` object or the `document` object or whatever object it is? Thank you

I know the `parseInt` was definded the `window` object, I am just using it as an example in general, I am not specifically asking what object definded the `parseInt` property.

Also, please don't show me jQuery codes since I don't know jQuery that very good.

Comment: Properties are in no sense "owned" in JavaScript.

Comment: What I mean is that who defined the property, it is basically owned by that object.

Comment: The `parseInt` function is a value, not a property. The `parseInt` identifier is a property of the `window` object.

Comment: @sixfingeredman What? `parseInt` is a function though, not a value?

Comment: @Teemu: He's conflating properties and the values they reference. Read his question carefully. `parseInt` is a value that is a function *(assuming we're talking about the function referenced by the `window.parseInt` property)*

Comment: @Alex, it's not a *global variable*, it's a *member of the global object*.

Comment: Your question is still pretty unclear. The concept of who defined a property is different from the concept of where a property was defined. A property is simply a member of an object. You always access a property directly from an object *except* in the case of global variables, which are properties of the `window` object, but can be accessed without referencing the `window` object explicitly.

Comment: @six fingered man what are you talking about? from what I learned, `parseInt` is function definded on the `window` object, so it is a property of the `window` object. What I am asking is that,  how do you know WHO definded a certain property, and I am using the `parseInt` function as an example in general

Comment: @Dummy: What I'm talking about is what I've described in my comments. Yes, `parseInt` is a property of the window object, which points to a function by default. If you're asking *who* defined it, then ask that. Your question starts with that, but then changes to *"...how do I know on which object it was defined"*, which is very different. Unless you're using *"who"* in a confusing way. An object doesn't define its own properties. Some other code does, or they're defined by the JS environment.

Comment: You must understand that by typing WHO in all caps, you've added no clarity. Do you mean which object owns the property? Do you mean which object(s) reference the value you're asking about? Do you mean which part of your code defined the property on a given object originally?

Comment: @Pointy: Properties are absolutely owned. That's why we talk about *"own properties"* vs *"inherited properties"*. Objects/functions on the other hand are not owned.

Comment: @Dummy How would you apply this information in practice? I.e. is there a practical example, where you would need to know, in what object some property is defined?

Comment: I admit that it is not practical, but if you have a curious mind, you'll understand that when you need to know something and you cant find the answer, you would feel like being on fire, so it was just out of curiosity and I wanted to know if it was possible or not. No question is a dumb question you know.

Comment: Yeah, ... who doesn't ask, never get answers. Notice, that though you can't get the "owner" of any native object, you can add a property containing the definitor to your own objects. If it would have some use later, I'm not sure.

Comment: @sixfingeredman well objects definitely "have" properties, but the point is that if you've got your hands on some random value it doesn't make much sense to wonder what object that value is a property of. (That's the way I interpreted the somewhat vague OP, at least.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to determine using code what the variable environment is of a given variable.

As for object properties, they should be obvious if they are `myObj.property`. If not obvious, it could be possible to use an exhaustive search to look for their existence in certain places, or certain known recursively.

Overall, it is not possible to know without looking at implementation documentation.

Comment: The ECMAScript specification states that `parseInt` is a property of the root `global` object. Its function definition is usually a built-in but can be overridden if necessary by script. Hypothetically you could search for an identical function property reference by recursively searching the property-tree but that wouldn't tell you anything significant.

Comment: @Dai - Yup, agree with all that :)

Comment: No I am using `parseInt` as an example in general, I know the `parseInt` function is defined on the `window` object. But I want to know how can you find WHO defined a certain property

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know that it is not possible, at least I dont have to try to search for an answer anymore. But would be great it were possible.

Comment: @Dummy - Usually if it is a requirement to know, you will keep that information around somewhere so that you can have a reference.

Comment: "*There is unfortunately no way to determine using code what the variable environment is of a given variable*". Yes. The ECMAScript specification does not provide any method to reference a "variable object" to, say, iterate the properties and find all variables within a particular execution context. And if you can't do that, you can't find all the objects within a context and hence can't iterate to find all their properties (and objects can be "anonymous", just like functions). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that to solve my question, we could use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`, but that would be very alot of typing because you have to type it out each time you need to know if a certain property is defined on a object. I have decided to write my own function to make this a little easier even though this is of no good practical use, I just wanted to satisfy my curiosity.

```
function findOwner(property, ownerObjectArray) {
    var result = []; // Array to store the objects that the given property is defined on

    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = arguments[i]; // the object currently being inspected
        var properyList= Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arguments[i]); // a list of all "Owned" properties by this object

        for (var j = 0; j < properyList.length; j++)
        {
            if (property === properyList[j]) result.push(obj.constructor);
        }
    }
                return result.length > 0 ? result : "undefinded";
}
```

run this method

```
window.onload = run;

    function run()
    {
        alert(findOwner("parseInt", Array.prototype, window, document));    // passing 3 objects we want to test against to this method. It printed : [object Window], the given property "parseInt" was found on the "Window" object
    }
```