# JavaScript Variables vs Properties

Tags: javascript, variables, properties

In JavaScript a global variable is also a property of the `window` object. What about local variables? Are they the property of any object?

For example:

```
var apple=3;
alert(apple);                   //  3
alert(window.apple);            //  same

thing();

function thing() {
    var banana=4;
    alert(banana);              //  4
    alert(thing.banana);        //  doesn’t work, of course
}
```

Is `banana` a property of any object

Comment: It's not (fortunately)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612087/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What about local variables? Are they the property of any object?

No. When execution enters a function, a new [*declarative environment record*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-declarative-environment-records) is created for storing the identifiers.

Unlike [*object environment records*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-environment-records) (used for creating the global and `with` environments) there is no user space object to which the variables are mapped.

See also [What really is a declarative environment record and how does it differ from an activation object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20139050/218196)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially the link. I guess the point here is that functions do not normally have their own Object Environment Record, while the global window object does.

Comment: *"while the global window object does"* Objects don't have environment records, environments have environments records. The global environment happens to have of a global environments record whose binding objects is `window` (which makes it the global object).

Answer (score 2):

But you can still store stuff inside function object. This way you can have something called **static** variable in languages like C/C++. For example:

```
function thing() {
    thing.banana = (thing.banana + 1) || 1;
    alert('This function was ran '+ thing.banana + ' times.');
}

thing(); // alerts "This function was ran 1 times"
thing(); // alerts "This function was ran 2 times"
thing(); // alerts "This function was ran 3 times"
thing(); // alerts "This function was ran 4 times"
thing(); // alerts "This function was ran 5 times"
alert(thing.banana) // alerts 5
```

Comment: I knew that, but thanks for making the point so that it’s part of this discussion. I takes advantage of the fact that a function is also an object.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this from [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and modify so that you can learn a bit more tricks. Check this example out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
In HTML, all global variables will become window variables.
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var apple=3;
var obj=new thing();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"I can display " + window.apple + " and " + window.banana + " but not local " + window.orange + ". I can call this from getter though " + obj.getOrange();


function thing() {
    banana=4;
    var orange=5;

    this.getOrange = function(){
        return orange;
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output will look like this.

```
In HTML, all global variables will become window variables.

I can display 3 and 4 but not local undefined. I can call this from getter though 5
```

So unless you create the getter and setter for local variables, you will not be able to reference them. Global cariables will become window varaibles.