# Difference between object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Im doing a course in frontend Dev in uni and the teacher insists on us using a old book so to learn the history and basics of JavaScript before we move on to more advanced and recent implementations.

Now in this book we are instructed to code a webpage for a food truck and it is supposed to take orders.

Now in some scripts the objects are defined like this :

```
function DataStore() {
    this.data = {};
  }
```

Here the data object is defined using the keyword "this" as in saying it belongs to the function  object DataStore.

however in some scripts the data object is defined as:

```
FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function() {
    console.log('Setting submit handler for form');
    this.$formElement.on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var data = {};
```

My question is what is the difference in the two data objects?

Comment: One's a *property*, the other one's just a *variable*. There's no connection beyond having the same name.

Comment: Is a property. a object in JS as well ?

Comment: Properties can be objects, yes.

Comment: this might help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491231/javascript-variables-vs-properties

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is at the bottom

### Long and boring introduction to how things work

When you write this :

```js
function SomeThing() { }
```

You can always do

```js
let a = new SomeThing();
```

even when it doesn't make sense like in :

```js
function lel() { console.log('lelelel'); }
let g = new lel();
console.log(g);
console.log(g.constructor.name);
```

What this means is that classes are actually the same as functions. And a function in which you use the keyword `this` usually means you will want to create instances of it.

now if I want all instances of my `lel()` <s>function</s> class to have a property called `foo` and a method called `bar` here's how you do :

```js
lel.prototype.foo = "Some initial value";
lel.prototype.bar = function() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
```

now I can do

```js
let g = new lel();
lel.bar();
lel.foo = "Hell yeah !";
lel.bar();
```

In conclusion, this :

```js
function SomeThing() {
  this.data = {};
}

SomeThing.prototype.setData = function(key, value) {
  this.data[key] = value;
}

SomeThing.prototype.getDataKeys = function() {
  return Object.keys(this.data);
}

SomeThing.prototype.getDataValues = function() {
  return Object.values(this.data);
}
```

is the same thing as this

```js
class SomeThing {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {};
  }

  setData(key, value) {
    this.data[key] = value;
  }

  getDataKeys() {
    return Object.keys(this.data);
  }

  getDataValues() {
    return Object.values(this.data);
  }
}
```

### Clarifications about your question

If somewhere in your code you have :

```
FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function() {
    console.log('Setting submit handler for form');
    this.$formElement.on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var data = {};
```

if **necessarily** means that somewhere else in your code you have

```
function FormHandler(...) { ... }
```

### Short answer

This :

```
function DataStore() {
  this.data = {};
}
```

is how you define a class named `DataStore` with a property called `data` initialized to the value `{}`

And this :

```
FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function() {
    ...
    var data = {};
}
```

is how you add a method called `addSubmitHandler` to the already defined class `FormHandler`. That method uses a local variable called `data`, could have been any other name

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, data is a property of the object that is created like this: `new DataStore`.
You can access this property like this:

```
var obj = new DataStore();
obj.data // => {}
/* or */
obj['data'] // => {}
```

In the second case, data is just a global variable, inside of an event handler, that is added executing the function.

```
var obj = new FormHandler();
obj.addSubmitHandler();
```

You access this variable like this:

```
data // => {}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to learn old JS. You would be out of date. You wouldn't be able to use latest technologies, and it would be harder to get a job.